# Перенос captcha из Fragment в Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, captcha

Имеется буквенная капча (captcha), записанная в отдельном фрагменте. Необходимо перенести ее из фрагмента в активность. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: `ctrl+C`->`ctrl+V`

Comment: @woesss а ты смешной, только я ожидал что то поумнее услышать

Comment: Какой вопрос - такой ответ. Если хочешь *что то поумнее* - не стесняйся в подробностях. Как из твоего вопроса понять что именно у тебя вызывает затруднения? По мне так всё просто - скопипастил код, потом исправил образовавшиеся ошибки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1: Создать в activity публичный метод `fun someMethod(captcha: String)`, который можно вызвать из фрагмента путём `(activity as? YourActivity)?.someMethod(captcha: String)`

Вариант 2: Если не требуется реактивное получение капчи, то можно во фрагменте сохранить её в SharedPreferences и достать уже в activity.